# How to use ng-ckeditor directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I've followed the following steps :

1. bower install ng-ckeditor
2. added `<script src="bower_components/ng-ckeditor/ng-ckeditor.js"></script>` in index.html
3. added in app.js like `angular.module('MyApp',['ngCkeditor'])`

   but now when i'm running the app i'm getting this issue, how to resolve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-ckeditor` internally uses `ckeditor`, so you should refer `ckeditor.js` before `ng-ckeditor`.

**Follow the steps mentioned below**

1. sudo npm install ckeditor
2. bower install ckeditor
3. bower install ng-ckeditor
4. add the following lines in index.html

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/ng-ckeditor/ng-ckeditor.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: getting 404 on adding above line. i'm using yomen. how to include ckeditor.js

Comment: @JasodeepChatterjee you have to install ckeditor component as well.. [check here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_package_managers) for more info